# add additional fields to a spring form when a button is clicked

Tags: ajax, forms, spring-mvc

I have the following class

```
public class Student {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private BigDecimal balance;
private List<Option> options;

...
}
```

and this is my form

```
    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="student">

    First name: <form:input path="firstName" />

    <br><br>

    Last name: <form:input path="lastName" />

    <br><br>

    Balance: <form:input path="balance" />

    <br><br>


    School Options: 

    <button onclick="addOptionForm('options')">Add a school option</button>

    <br><br>

    <div id="options"></div>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form:form>
```

the AJAX function is

```
function addOptionForm(id) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "option-form", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

I tried using AJAX to load the extra fields when the `Add school option` button is clicked. The problem is that the form is submitted after clicking the button.

so is there a way to do this with JavaScript or AJAX, and can I access the list from the bound Student object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute `type='button'` to prevent submitting. `type='submit'` is the default behaviour for `button`.

`<button type="button" onclick="addOptionForm('options')">Add a school option</button>`

Comment: Is that the cause of the form submitting?

Comment: @AmmarSamater Ignore my previous anwer